# Set select on form using casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, html-select, casperjs, multi-select

My form has two select boxes in which the user can pick countries to be included in the settings.  The values of the available options look like this:

```
<option value="AU">Australia</option>
```

When the form is submitted, chrome reports the state of the select like this:

```
f_countries:selectedc
selectedcountries[]:AU
selectedcountries[]:AR
```

On casperjs I can use the following method to do things such as type in input boxes, etc., on the form.  What I can't figure out is how to set the select form values to those listed above.

For example, say I wanted to set the selected countries to "US,CA,BR".

Here is what I use for other types of input on the forms.

```
this.fill('form#my_form', { 
'username': 'joe',
'password': 'secret',
'f_countries:selectedc': [[ can't figure out what goes here ]]
}, true);
```

Question is: how do I use casperjs to set the values of selects on forms.

Comment: Are both select boxes named the same or do you mean a multi-select box? Please show more of the markup (just selects and options).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CasperJS/ Javascript Selecting Multiple Options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30986521/casperjs-javascript-selecting-multiple-options)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a simple select box, try using

selector : 'value'

if it is a multi select box , refer to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/casperjs/1iObXfhfbUU